# How can I change the log level identifier printed out in JBoss EAP 7 log?

Tags: java, logging, jboss, formatter

I need to change the way JBoss prints out the log level into the log file, showing only the first character of the log level label, so that

```
19:13:01,183 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.12-jbossorg-2  ...
```

will become

```
19:13:01,183 I [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.12-jbossorg-2  for context '/MONService'
```

I tried some combination of formatting strings but I am unable to get only the first character.

I refered to the JBoss EAP 7 documentation (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/configuration_guide/logging_with_jboss_eap) and the Formatter javadoc (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) but was unable to find any viable solution.

Could anybody help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I tried this format and it works (for JBoss AS 7.5 at least):

```
<pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %1.1p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
```

This is configured in the standalone.xml:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.5">
            ...
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
            ...
            <root-logger>
                <level name="ALL"/>
                <handlers>                    
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
            <formatter name="PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %1.1p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
</subsystem>
```